# Threading for updating datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, dispatcher

I have a window with a telerik gridview in it and i update this gridview every 1 minute. i have a refresh method and every 1 minute i call it.

i cant use BackgroundWorker because my CollectionViewSource is in the UI thread and backgroundworker cant use it. my question is how can i call this refresh method from another thread?

somewhere i see this sample code:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Refresh()));
```

is this a true way that i use the above code in Refresh_Executed?
please help me.

this is my Refresh method:

```
public ObservableCollection<RequestView> AllRequestsData { get; set; }

private void Refresh()
    {
        using (ArchiveEntities db = new ArchiveEntities())
        {
            var data = db.RequestSyncs.Where(x => x.UserId == null);
            if (data.Any())
            {
                string IdList = String.Join(",", data.Where(x => x.IsNew).Select(x => x.RequestId));
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IdList))
                {
                    foreach (var item in db.RequestViews.Where("it.id in {" + IdList + "}"))
                    {
                        this.AllRequestsData.Add(item);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var item in data.Where(x => x.IsDeleted))
                {
                    RequestView rv = this.AllRequestsData.Where(x => x.Id == item.RequestId).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (rv != null)
                    {
                        this.AllRequestsData.Remove(rv);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    db.RequestSyncs.DeleteObject(item);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be in common it's true way, but it depends on content of the `Refresh` method, could you provide the content of it?

*EDIT*
Usually I load data in view model using async theads and don't really need to update RadGridView. But when, for instance, I need to collapse all groups e.t.c I use radGridView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...).

**UPDATE**

There is no need to update `RadGridView`. You are updating it's `ItemsSource` property. I would not reccomend to use `Dispatcher` in such situation and I would use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to recieve plain data from database and update `ItemsSource` with the synchronization with the current UI thread:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<RequestSyncPlain>>(() =>
{
  return result;
}).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
  try
  {
    _.Wait();
  }
  catch (AggregateException ae)
  {
  }

  foreach (var requestSyncPlain in _.Result)
  {
    var requestSync = new RequestSyncViewModel(requestSyncPlain);

    requestSyncObservableCollection.Add(requestSync);
  }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Note, that you should upgrade this method to implement your needs (you could put you database methods in first task and may be return `Tuple` from two colelctions) and this is just idea.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using the `Dispatcher` is the correct way to do most light background work.

Be warned however that heavy background work done on the `Dispatcher` can lock up the UI, since it is still running on the main UI thread. If you have a large amount of processing I would recommend using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), or some other form of multi-threading (I prefer `await`/`async`, however that's only available in C#5.0 or the [AsyncCTP Refresh](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/13/async-ctp-refresh-installation.aspx))

Also, I would recommend refreshing the Collection the `DataGrid` is bound to instead of the `DataGrid` itself. I think refreshing the DataGrid will re-draw all the UI elements, while refreshing the `ItemsSource` will simply re-use the existing UI elements if possible.

Comment: i post my Refresh method. is it a VERY HEAVY work? thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the TPL is the best way to go when it comes to threading since .NET 4 was released...

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.Refresh())
```